# Renaming JIRA Issues

Tags: jira, release-management

Is it possible to rename an issue for a given project in JIRA?

For example, if I have a project named `equities` and I create an issue from the JIRA GUI, the new issue is named something like `equities-1`.

Could I rename the issue to something like `equities_1.0.0`?

I am trying to create a release management workflow in JIRA and need to enforce strict naming conventions. Hence, why I need to change the name.

Comment: In our implementation of Jira, Issue names can be changed just by click on the Issue title when you are viewing the detail. I'm using version v6.0.8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry but you can't.

What you are calling a "name" is indeed a key automatically generated by JIRA :
[PROJECT_KEY]-[SEQUENCE_NUMBER].
You can never change it.

For your release management workflow, I think you should try another field :

- "summary" field,
- or why not a brand new custom field,
- or use the "fix_version" field

I hope it helps

Comment: I agree, what you would consider the "name" of an issue is usually the summary field. But if you want to do a release workflow you should see if the fixVersion field works for you. This usually is used to indicate in which version a feature or fix was included or will be included.